# jQuery pop up on certain areas of an image

Tags: jquery, image, popup, imagemap

I have an image, which I'm not keen on splicing, what I want to happen is for a user to hover over certain areas of the image I define and a different pop up box will occur, depending on what section of the image the user hovers over.

The actual pop up code is not an issue, what I am looking for is advice on whether it's possible to have different popups occur, depending on what area of the image a user hovers over with their mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for an [image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map).

Answer (score 0):

Check out `<MAP>`, basically you define different areas as links. I would assume hover events would work just the same. Not sure about how it integrates with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using an image map. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp